# I update mi Integration Studio WSO2 IDE from version 8.0.0 to 8.2.0

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

i was use Integration Studio 8.0.0, the Eclipse based WSO2 IDE the which functioned perfect, for indication of my leader i updated to 8.2.0 versión and when i run a CompositerExporter trought "Export Project Artifcats and Run" for start the Micro Integrator server trought the IDE in the console shows the next error:

```
LOG INTEGRACION IDE WSO2

2023-07-21 12:50:06,300 main ERROR Unable to create file ${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon.log java.io.IOException: El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:438)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:620)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:645)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

2023-07-21 12:50:06,304 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@2bd08376] unable to create manager for [${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@e70f13a[pattern=${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=20, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=TID: [%d] %5p {%c} - %m {%c}%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@2bd08376] unable to create manager for [${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@e70f13a[pattern=${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=20, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=TID: [%d] %5p {%c} - %m {%c}%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

2023-07-21 12:50:06,304 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

2023-07-21 12:50:06,308 main ERROR Unable to create file ${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-trace-messages.log java.io.IOException: El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:438)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:620)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:645)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

2023-07-21 12:50:06,308 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@2bd08376] unable to create manager for [${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-trace-messages.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@7a1234bf[pattern=${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-trace-messages-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=20, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d] %5p {%c} - %m {%c}%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@2bd08376] unable to create manager for [${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-trace-messages.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@7a1234bf[pattern=${sys:logfiles.home}/wso2carbon-trace-messages-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=20, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d] %5p {%c} - %m {%c}%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

2023-07-21 12:50:06,308 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

2023-07-21 12:50:06,313 main ERROR FileManager (${sys:logfiles.home}/patches.log) java.io.IOException: El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos java.io.IOException: El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:438)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:620)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:645)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:434)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:422)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:96)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogAdapter.getContext(LogAdapter.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)
```

Ok, finally indepently that my service run correcty at the start of the console log shows an error relationed with the log but directory level, i think that have error at moment of create log file in her directory specified, some can guide to me for solve this error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is known [issue](https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/1845) in Windows environments and we have already fixed this in the latest WSO2 Integration Studio 8.2.0. You will need to update the Studio to the latest version by following the below steps.

1. Start WSO2 Integration Studio
2. Go to Help -> Check for Updates

[image]

3. Once the update check is completed, you can select all the available updates and install.

For more information about Integration Studio refer the following doc,

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/installing-wso2-integration-studio/#get-the-latest-updates